# Display Months in Column Chart That have no Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS column chart with two category groups for the x-axis that sort the data based on the year first, followed by the date. I additionally have a parameter on the chart in which the end user can pick the month in which they wish to see the data, and the chart displays any data relevant to that month.. What I am trying to do is have the chart display the columns for all months, even if there is no information available for that month (ideally, I would like for the month to display 0 is there is no data), as opposed to just the months which have data based on the filter. This is the query I have in my dataset:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.statecodename) AS codename,
         c.statecodename,
         DATENAME(mm, c.expireson) AS Month,
         DATENAME(yyyy, c.expireson) AS Year,
         DATEPART(yyyy, c.expireson) AS YearNum,
         DATEPART(m, c.expireson) AS MonthNum

FROM Table1 AS c

WHERE (c.expireson IS NOT NULL) 
AND (DATENAME(mm, c.modifiedon) IN (@ReportParameter1))


GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, c.expireson), 
               DATENAME(yyyy, c.expireson),
               DATEPART(yyyy, c.expireson), 
               DATEPART(m, c.expireson),
               c.statecodename

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(d.statecodename) AS codename,
         d.statecodename collate DATABASE_DEFAULT,
         DATENAME(mm, d.expireson) AS Month,
         DATENAME(yyyy, d.expireson) AS Year,
         DATEPART(yyyy, d.expireson) AS YearNum,
         DATEPART(m, d.expireson) AS MonthNum

FROM Table2 AS d

WHERE (d.expireson IS NOT NULL) 
AND (DATENAME(mm, d.modifiedon) IN (@ReportParameter1))

GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, d.expireson), 
          DATENAME(yyyy, d.expireson), 
          DATEPART(yyyy, d.expireson), 
          DATEPART(m, d.expireson), 
          d.statecodename

ORDER BY YearNum, MonthNum
```

Is there a way in which I can assign null values to the rest of the months so that they display as such in the column chart? So far I have tried to create a dataset which retrieved all the months, and used a lookup expression for my month parameter, but that did not do anything. I have also tried to check in my WHERE clause for DATENAME(mm, c.expireson) IS NULL but that also did not work. Could anyone offer me an approach as to how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary or variable table with the year and month like this:

Select your year and month from that table with a left join to the query you've listed above on the year and month.

```
declare @date as datetime
declare @forecast TABLE ([yy] int, [mm] varchar(15))
set @date = getdate()
While (select datediff(m,@date,getdate())) > -12
Begin
Insert into @forecast (yy, mm) values (datepart(year,@date),datename(month,@date))
set @date = dateadd(m,-1,@date)
IF (select datediff(m,@date,getdate())) > 23
Break
Else
Continue
END

SELECT f.yy, f.mm,
a.codename, 
a.statecodename
FROM @forecast f
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(c.statecodename) AS codename,
         c.statecodename,
         DATENAME(mm, c.expireson) AS Month,
         DATENAME(yyyy, c.expireson) AS Year
FROM Table1 AS c

WHERE (c.expireson IS NOT NULL) 
AND (DATENAME(mm, c.modifiedon) IN (@ReportParameter1))

GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, c.expireson), 
         DATENAME(yyyy, c.expireson),
         c.statecodename

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(d.statecodename) AS codename,
         d.statecodename collate DATABASE_DEFAULT,
         DATENAME(mm, d.expireson) AS [Month],
         DATENAME(yyyy, d.expireson) AS [Year]

FROM Table2 AS d

WHERE (d.expireson IS NOT NULL) 
AND (DATENAME(mm, d.modifiedon) IN (@ReportParameter1))

GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, d.expireson), 
          DATENAME(yyyy, d.expireson), 
          d.statecodename
          ) a
 on f.yy = a.[year] and f.mm = a.[month]
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried to implement this code to create the temporary table. However, upon running the code I got an error message :'Cannot find either column "c" or the user defined aggregate "c.DATENAME", or the name is ambiguous. This occurred when I performed the left join temp.mm = c.DATENAME(mm, c.expireson). temp is the @forecast table.

Comment: Make sure your query looks like this:                        SELECT   COUNT(c.statecodename) AS codename,
         c.statecodename,
         f.mm AS Month,
         f.yy AS Year,
         DATEPART(yyyy, c.expireson) AS YearNum,
         DATEPART(m, c.expireson) AS MonthNum

FROM 
@forefast f
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table1 AS c on f.yy =  DATENAME(yyyy, c.expireson)
and f.mm = DATENAME(mm, c.expireson)

Comment: I corrected it, as you mentioned, but I am still unable to display all the months. I tried to remove the parameter and in my query tried to test setting datename to a specific month, and I still cannot get all the months displayed. Is there any reason why this may be so?

Comment: The where clause for the left-joined table is essentially turning the join into an inner join. You can join your query as a derived table to the temp table. I'll edit the code of my original answer with an example.

Comment: Based on your example, I tried as you suggested, and now it tells me that "The multi-part identifier "c.expireson" could not be bound" Is this because of the join?

Comment: Were there modifications to the query I posted? Are you getting the error from SSMS or is it coming from another tool? It's difficult to write problem free code without knowing anything about the tables or underlying data, but we may be able to find the problem without you needing to post a lot of other information.

Comment: The only modification I made was that I balanced out the select statements so they reference the same variables (so I basically added DATEPART year and month) to the code inside of the parantheses due to the union. I am getting the error directly from ssrs, and from what research I'm doing, this error usually occurs because of the way the JOINs are used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66499/discussion-between-jared-s-and-sabr786).